# I have done simple data transaction on ropsten, it's stll increasing blocks confirmation

Tags: solidity, web3js, ether, blocks

**Why there are so many block confirmations in small transaction?**

**How blocks are working while transaction?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what software you're looking at, but "confirmations" usually just means how many blocks have been mined after the one with your transaction in it. That number should go up by 1 roughly every 10-15 seconds, because that's how long it takes to mine a block. It will keep going up forever.